# Export Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I need to export a running k8s cluster , and import it in a new one , i know it could be not the best approach, but i do not have access to any documentation from the running one, can you recommend tools to do so ? i know i could face some issues with volumes or network, but i believe those can be correct later, i have access to the controller, and i can see the running pods /services

```
ubuntu@xxxxxxxxx:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS           AGE
xxxxxxx                         2/2     Running            0                  138d
xxxxxxx                         2/2     Running            0                  2d22h
xxxxxxx                         2/2     Running            0                  138d
xxxxxxx                         0/1     Completed          0                  97d
xxxxxxx                         0/1     Completed          0                  97d

Please advise, thanks.
```

Comment: So you want to dump every resources (pods, deployments, services, etc.) from the running k8s cluster and reimport it to a fresh one? What kind of workloads do you want to migrate? Only default k8s resources (pods/services)? Or also resources managed by CRDs? Also, do you want to migrate resources on ALL namespaces?

Comment: I do not need to CRD, only the default resources, and they are all already deployed in the default namespace.

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to "just" `kubectl get -n default pods,services,configmaps,[...] -o yaml > resources.yaml`, and then `kubectl apply -f resources.yaml` on your new cluster. You may have to remove some stuff from `resources.yaml` so that it works on the new cluster.

Comment: Thank you, its seems exported everything, anyway i am going to re arrange it before importing into new cluster, will confirm it once done, thanks again.

Comment: I'd normally expect to do this by provisioning the new cluster, and then running the same `kubectl apply`, `helm install`, `helmfile apply`, _etc._ commands I used to install software on the original cluster.  This doesn't really seem to be a programming-oriented problem, though.

Comment: Konveyor Crane, https://github.com/migtools/crane, might help. You could also try Velero.